# Concatenate pandas objects where one is a one-dimensional pd ndarray

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have a long pd dataframe `mydf` and a one-dimensional ndarray, with the same columns names and type, created like this:

```
Row = pd.Series(0, mydf.columns)
Row = mydf.iloc[index]
```

I want to add the `Row` in a defined position `i` in the middle of the dataframe `mydf`. Thereofre I use following:

```
mydf = pd.concat([mydf.head(idx), Row , mydf.tail(len(mydf) - idx)])
```

I always get the following warning and then the codes doesn't  run:

```
 '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str', sort order is undefined for incomparable objects 
result = result.union(other)
```

How can the error come if my `Row` has exactly the same format like the dataframe?  How to fix this ?

Thx.

Comment: df.tail(... ?? Is thata typo. It should be `mydf` na

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 0):

What you are getting is just a warning the Row is begining concatenated to the dataframe not in a proper way.

Row is a series and you are trying to concat series between two dataframes. Series has index dtype object (string) and df has index dtype int. Index will be sorted usually when concatenated. Now the function doesn't know how to sort the mixed dtype index. So you get that warning.

So better convert Row to dataframe to avoid this error i.e

```
ndf = pd.concat([mydf.head(index), pd.DataFrame(Row).T, mydf.tail(len(mydf) - index)])
```

For Example consider the dataframe
mydf

```
   id  offset  code
0   1       3    21
1   1       3    24
2   1       5    21
```

```
index= 2 
Row = mydf.iloc[index]
df = pd.concat([mydf.head(index), Row , mydf.tail(len(mydf) - index)])

/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/api.py:77: RuntimeWarning: unorderable types: str() < int(), sort order is undefined for incomparable objects
result = result.union(other)
```

```
       id  offset  code     0
0       1.0     3.0  21.0   NaN
1       1.0     3.0  24.0   NaN
id      NaN     NaN   NaN   1.0
offset  NaN     NaN   NaN   5.0
code    NaN     NaN   NaN  21.0
2       1.0     5.0  21.0   NaN
```

```
df = pd.concat([mydf.head(index), pd.DataFrame(Row).T , mydf.tail(len(mydf) - index)])
```

```
   id  offset  code
0   1       3    21
1   1       3    24
2   1       5    21
2   1       5    21
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.. it unfortunately still doesn't work. The weird thing is that it works when I write the result in an new empty DataFrame but not when I write it back in mydf

Comment: Because I'd like to have it like this: 
`mydf = pd.concat([mydf.head(idx), Row , mydf.tail(len(mydf) - idx)])`